# T-SQL schema changes that can be performed in O(1)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, schema-migration

We want to minimize the downtime for our users during the upgrade process and want to ensure that our schema changes can all be performed in O(1) and are not O(n). Is there a list of documented schema changes that can be performed in O(1) with Microsoft SQL Server?

E.g. adding a nullable column is O(1) - at least our empiric tests show that.

Comment: The term you are looking for is "metadata-only changes" see https://sqlperformance.com/2020/04/database-design/new-metadata-column-changes-sql-server-2016

Comment: Thank you, do you know of any official documentation of metadata-only changes?

Comment: Maybe at least for the new Azure SQL database server?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#adding-not-null-columns-as-an-online-operation also see https://sqljudo.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/when-is-alter-table-just-a-meta-data-change/

Comment: "Online changes" is another term probably relevant to what you're looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine if an ALTER statement will be a metadata-only operation O(1) or a size of data operation O(n)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/263934/how-to-determine-if-an-alter-statement-will-be-a-metadata-only-operation-o1-or)

Comment: @Zikato: Thanks, I've found that thread before. It doesn't contain a "list" as well, the reply I got here so far is better.

Answer (score 4):

[This blog post by Russ Thomas – SQL Judo](https://sqljudo.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/when-is-alter-table-just-a-meta-data-change/), as shared by one of the commenters here, has a list of several O(1) commands.

I'll do my best to create a more extensive list here.

Please note that while these commands are performed in **O(1)**, some may require **very high-level locks**, and therefore may cause **contention** with other sessions in the database. Especially when potentially affecting **dependent** objects such as **indexed views** and **foreign key** constraints.

So, please don't take them lightly.

All of the following commands will be performed in O(1), not including waiting on locks on database objects:

- All `CREATE` commands, except `CREATE INDEX` (this does **not** include `ALTER TABLE ... ADD ...` commands).
- All `DROP` commands, except the `DROP` of a `CLUSTERED INDEX`.
- Adding a new **nullable** column at the **end** of a table's columns list.
- `ALTER TABLE ... SWITCH TO ...` - this is commonly identified with partitioning, but you don't actually require partitioning on a table in order to use it. This is because technically, since SQL 2005, ALL tables are partitioned (having only partition 1 by default).
- `CREATE NONCLUSTERED ... INDEX ... ON ... WITH STATISTICS_ONLY` - this creates a **hypothetical index** in O(1).
- All `ALTER TABLE ... DROP ...` commands, except the `DROP` of a `CLUSTERED` constraint (such as a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraint).
- `ALTER TABLE ... ADD CONSTRAINT ... WITH NOCHECK` (the `NOCHECK` option is crucial for avoiding retroactively checking all existing data in the table).
- `ALTER TABLE ... ADD DEFAULT ...` on an existing column should be performed in O(1).
- `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN ...` when **increasing** the maxsize of **variable** length columns (varchar, nvarchar, varbinary) should be performed in O(1).
- [Starting with SQL 2016](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/04/database-design/new-metadata-column-changes-sql-server-2016), in some very rare cases, with **data compression** enabled, it's also possible to **increase** fixed-size **numerical** columns (e.g. tinyint to smallint to int to bigint, or decimal(14,1) to decimal(18,9)). But [in most cases this would not be possible so be careful with it](https://eitanblumin.com/2020/05/04/the-new-metadata-only-column-changes-feature-in-sql-server-2016-is-useless/).

If I recall additional commands, I'll edit this message and add them to the list.

Comment: Adding a non-nullable column with a default also?

Comment: I hate to be the _uhm, ackshually..._-guy, but I don't feel it's correct at all to refer to these operations as "O(1)" because operations aren't algorithms, and plenty of these operations will internally involve _some_ algorithms with time and space complexity beyond O(1) - e.g. adding a new column to a table with `n` columns is _necessarily_ O(n), except the time-per-`n` is tiny... and so on and so forth...

Comment: ALTER TABLE ... ADD DEFAULT ... observed to be not O(1) ... oh wait you mean add just the default constraint not the column

Comment: @Dai I'm gonna have to be the _uhm, ackshually.._ guy in return and say that - when it comes to databases and O(n) calculations, "n" normally represents the DATA, not something that's schema-based such as number of columns.